# using .ajax() in .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to iterate through elements of .ball class and check if their associated url exists:

```
$(".ball").each(function(i){

    var url;

    var c_day = $(this).data('day');
    var c_mon = $(this).data('mon');
    var c_year = $(this).data('year');

    url = c_year + "/" + c_mon + "/" + c_day + ".html";

    $.ajax({

        url: url, 
        error: function()
        {
              alert('file: ' + url + '   does not exist');
        },
        success: function()
        {
            alert('file: ' + url + 'EXXXXXXISTS!!!!!');
            blogA[ blog_count ] = url;
            blog_count++;
            $(this).css("color", "red" );           
        }
    });
 });
```

I've done some research and read that using .ajax in .each causes a lot of problems but I couldn't wrap my head around on how to fix it.

The problem is that I get really weird results (has to do with asynchronous?). If I alert url outside of ajax, it correctly iterates through the elements. If I alert url in ajax, it spits out urls that belong to the last element of the class.

Comment: Fix what? What is the error?

Comment: "using .ajax in .each causes a lot of problem" --- don't follow blindly advices, but try to get why those advices were done. Not surprisingly there are a lot of silly people giving stupid advices over the internet, and it's likely you've found some of them.

Comment: `$(this)` over and over again is bad practice. Store it in a variable

Comment: @elclanrs : Sorry about that. The problem is that I get really weird results (has to do with asynchronous?). If I alert url outside of ajax, it correctly iterates through the elements. If I alert url in ajax, it spits out urls that belong to the last element of the class.

Comment: Now this doesn't make any sense, frankly speaking. `varing` the `url` binds it to the function context, so both `error` and `success` functions (which are also created within this function) will point to its own `url`. Are you sure you've shown the whole story here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this, in order to simplify your code

```
function successHandler(url, ball) {
  return function(ret) {
     alert('file: ' + url + 'EXXXXXXISTS!!!!!');
     ball.css('color','red')
  }
}

var balls = $('.ball'), requests = []


balls.each(function(index, ball) {
  var url = ...
  requests.push($.ajax({ url : url , success : successHandler(url, ball) })
})

$.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {
  alert('all balls are checked')
})
```

Or with ES6:

```
const success = (url,ball)=>(ret)=>ball.css('color','red')

const balls = $('.balls')
    , reqs = balls.map( (b, i) => {
        const url = ...
        return $.ajax({url, success:success(url,ball)})
    })

$.when.apply($, reqs).done( (resps) => alert('all done'))
```

A Little explanation: You are blindly using `this` in your callback, not knowing in which context it is going to be executed. In order to work around it and has your URL into callback we are creating function that returns a function, so it will have URL of current `.ball` DOM object in the context.

You'll probably also need to execute code after all ajax requests are done, so using `$.when` is the simplest way of doing it. And we are storing all promises just for this reason.

Comment: Indeed, very nice approach.

Comment: And if you wanted to handle them in order, you can do so by iterating over the arguments object in the done callback.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't concerned about the order of execution of each ajax call and just want to know when they are all done and the array is fully populated, then you can get this to work by fixing your reference to `this` and by adding a callback function that is called when all items are done:

```
// this function called when the ajax calls for all balls have finished
// at this point, blogA and blog_count will be populated
function ballsDone() {
    // put your code here
}

var balls = $(".ball");
var cnt = balls.length;
balls.each(function(i){

    var url;
    var self = $(this);

    var c_day = self.data('day');
    var c_mon = self.data('mon');
    var c_year = self.data('year');

    url = c_year + "/" + c_mon + "/" + c_day + ".html";

    $.ajax({

        url: url, 
        error: function()
        {
              alert('file: ' + url + '   does not exist');
              if (--cnt <= 0) {
                  ballsDone();
              }
        },
        success: function()
        {
            blogA[ blog_count ] = url;
            blog_count++;
            self.css("color", "red" );           
            if (--cnt <= 0) {
                ballsDone();
            }
        }
    });
 });
```

Keep in mind that the ajax calls are asynchronous so the ONLY place you can use the results from the ajax call is in the success handler.  You can't use the results of the ajax calls right after the `.each()` call in a synchronous fashion because the ajax calls have not yet finished.  You must wait for the success handler to be called and when `cnt` success handlers have been called, then they are all done and you can then process the results.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Should I only access blogA in the ballsDone() function?

Comment: @Andy - yes, you are correct.  `blogA` and `blog_count` are not completely populated until `ballsDone()` is called.